# How does C# 5 async return to main thread?

Tags: c#-5.0, async-ctp

I was watching a vid about Async CTP and saw that if you call await from e.g. main thread , then the execution will continue from main thread when the work is completed.

e.g

```
//called from main thread
var result = await SomeAsyncWork();
//this will execute in main thread also
console.writeline(result)
```

I had the naive impression that there would be a normal call back going on which would be executed on a worker thread.

At some level that must be what is going on since you can wrap normal async methods in a Task of T with Task.FromAsync

but normal async methods will run in worker threads, so how is the callback in the workerthread marshalled back to the main thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback is attached to the task, using the current task scheduler (that's "current" at the time of awaiting, not current at the time of completion). For a UI thread, the current task scheduler will schedule the callback to be executed within the UI thread... for a thread pool thread, the scheduler will allow it to be executed on *any* thread pool thread, etc.

Assuming you're awaiting a `Task<T>`, it's effectively calling [`Task<T>.ContinueWith(continuationAction, scheduler)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321307.aspx).

You can await anything with the right methods available, but how `BeginAwait` schedules the continuation is implementation-specific. I've only mentioned the task-based one because it's probably the most common one. The compiler itself doesn't specify this at all - it assumes that the libraries will do the right thing. All the compiler does is translate "the rest of the method" into a continuation, and pass that into `BeginAwait`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler compiles your code differently and splits it so that code after await becomes a callback. There's a detailed explanation to a certain extent here:
http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/c-5-await-and-async-in-asp-net/